# HttpListener with SSL support not getting any connections from remote computer

Tags: c#, ssl, https, httplistener

I am trying to create a simple web server with SSL support. I am trying to use HttpListener for this. This is what I have:

- I made a root CA certificate and stored it in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store
- I derived a certificate for server authentication from my root certificate and stored that in the Personal store
- I bound the certificate to my application and port with the 'netsh http add sslcert ...'-command.
- I also stored my root CA certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorites store of another computer.

Here is some code that I used:

```
private void StartServer()
{
    HttpListener server = new HttpListener();
    server.Prefixes.Add("http://+:8080/");
    server.Prefixes.Add("https://+:8081/");
    server.Start();
    server.BeginContext(HandleRequestCallback, server);
}

private void (HandleRequestCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    HttpListener server = ar.AsyncState as HttpListener;
    server.BeginGetContext(HandleRequestCallback, server); // Start listening again.
    HttpListenerContext context = server.EndGetContext(ar);
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
    ProcessRequest(request);
}
```

This is what works:

- An ordinary http request from the local machine
- A secure https request from the local machine (I get a green lock symbol in Chrome)
- An ordinary http request from the remote machine

What doesn't work is a secure https request from the remote machine. The connection simply times out. Debugging in VS shows that the HandleRequest method doesn't get hit. Also playing around with Fiddler, I can't see any incoming network traffic in this case.

I have also made a similar solution using TcpListener (and SslStream), and with that, I do get a secure connection from the remote computer. So it is not a firewall issue...

Did someone else encounter this issue? Is there someone who can point me to what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you see any network traffic with something like Wireshark? If so, what do you see of the SSL connection attempt?

Comment: This looks more like a network issue than an issue with your program. My guess is that the access is simply blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Yes, I do see incoming network traffic with Wireshark. But, this being SSL, I don't know what to make of it...